# What is known about the equidistribution properties of Philox pseudo random number generator?

Tags: pseudo-random-generators

I want to evaluate the usefulness of Philox pseudo random number generator for drawing multidimensional random vectors. What is known about the equidistribution properties of Philox?

I read the Philox paper but it does not contain any information about its equidistribution properties.

Comment: You don't need us to answer such questions. Instead, do a literature search. Start with the paper introducing Philox, and go over the papers citing it. Also, try searching using keywords such as Philox, equidistribution, randomness, quality, and so on.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95390/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51405240/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: I posted it on StackOverflow by mistake (I intended to post it here only) and they will close it as off-topic. I noticed that I can delete the post there, which I did.

Comment: @D.W. How is a question about the properties of a PRNG off-topic for Computer Science? Can you please explain?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I read the Philox paper. It doesn't mention equidistribution properties. Neither did the Google search bring any useful leads.

Comment: Check this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6193.pdf.

Comment: They report equidistribution tests for XORShift generators, not for Philox.

Comment: @quant_dev, see my comment above.  It's not off-topic; it's closed because it was cross-posted on Stack Overflow.  I notice you deleted the copy on Stack Overflow, so I will re-open this.

Comment: Rather than leaving comments explaining what research you've done, please edit the question to show what research you've already done.

Comment: Check Table 2 on page 15.

Comment: @D.W. "Rather than leaving comments explaining what research you've done, please edit the question to show what research you've already done."

I did.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I can't see any equidistribution results there. Which column do you mean? Ising test? I don't think it's the same thing.